# Billing from card directly

Tags: php, billing

I, for the life of me, cannot find any literature on this, simply because I have no clue how it is called.

I want to learn how to implement a payment option that consists of paying with your credit/debit card directly without the use of a third party like paypal.

This is what I am talking about

[image]

Can you please give me some information about how this payment method is called and possibly some articles I can read up on. Thank you!

Comment: recommended reading: **[Where to start](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6367/31260)**

Comment: Having spent several years writing software for the payment card industry (i.e. credit card processing) I can safely say that if you have to ask this question, you should _not_ be implementing that software. You really need to work closely with an expert who knows the proper way to do this and who can ensure your project meets the relevant laws and industry regulations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to have an account with a payment processor company. If not PayPal, there are others. Moneris is one.

Usually, your payment processing partner will send you an API which contains the code necessary to submit a payment. You use the API to make calls to the payment processor, but you don't submit raw HTTP requests to them.

You'll might also want to look in to [PCI Compliance](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You need a payment processor. Paypal is one of many, but you need SOMEONE to process cards for you. Among other issues 'Mastercard' is a global brand, but cards are issued by MANY banks, and to process a card, someone has to route the processing to the proper bank. That's what a payment processor does.